# Set Excel / Word Online document readonly using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

When an Excel or Word file on SharePoint is opened,it is in edit mode by default.
From Excel/Word online menu, there is a menu option to set the file read-only, called "Protect Workbook" in Excel inline and "Protect Document" in Word online, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Next time the file is open in Excel/Word online, it is opened in read-only mode and shows an "Edit Anyway" button to switch to edit mode, which is exactly what I need.

[image]

Question is: How can I use Graph API to programatically set an Excel or Word document as read-only?

Comment: you can do that as read only in share permissions

Comment: Kindly look in to permission section of the microsoft graph api under files category

Answer (score 0):

HTTP request

POST /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/protection/protect

Request headers
Name    Description
Authorization   Bearer {token}. Required.
Workbook-Session-Id Workbook session Id that determines if changes are persisted or not. Optional.
Request body
In the request body, provide a JSON object with the following parameters.

Parameter   Type    Description
options WorkbookWorksheetProtectionOptions  Optional. sheet protection options.
Response

If successful, this method returns 200 OK response code. It does not return anything in the response body.

Kindly look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheetprotection-protect?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http for more Information

Comment: I don't think WorkbookWorksheetProtectionOptions is the right one. The readonly protection I need is at file level, not at worksheet level. Can you provide code example?

Comment: I fully tested your solution. It doesn't work same as "Protect Workbook" from Excel online UI, but by setting all WorkbookWorksheetProtectionOptions properties as false, it prevents user editing a Worksheet. The downside is having to set every worksheet in a workbook and there's no quick way to reenable editing an Excel file. I appreciate your answer though so I'm giving you the bounty points.